# 1 to many mysql statment plus showing images and text

Tags: php, mysql, one-to-many

Hi everyone I have a little problem with this one to many statment. I am adding images in the mysql database and in a folder that part is perfect. But when I want to display them that is my tricky part. I don't know where is my problem in the way I've created the database or in my code. So here are both:

My two tables are text and imagess
In the text table:
text_id - primary
text_field - unique

In the imagess table:
id - primary
name
title
path

My code is this:

```
     <?php

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM text text_id, imagess id WHERE (text_id=id AND text_field=title) ");

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     echo '<br>№'.$row['text_id'].'<br>';

     echo''.$row['title'].'<br>'
     .$row['text_field'];

     echo'<br><img src="'.$row['path'].'?url='.$row['path'].'/>';
     }

     ?>
```

My goal is to learn how to display the 1 title + text with 2-3 images. I hope someone could explain me where are my mistakes because from the book I am reading there is not such thing.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The SQL query is obviously not right, but I can't correct it for you without seeing the full structure of the tables you're tryin' to use

Comment: can you paste a sample output of that query ?

Comment: @Bgi My tables are like this:
imagess
id INT 11 NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary;
name varchar(50) NOT NULL;
title varchar(80) NOT NULL;
path varchar(100) NOT NULL;


For the text table:
text_id - primary int 11 not null auto increment;
text_field - unique varchar 80 not null;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a 1-to-many relation, all you have to ignore multiples occurences of the "1".
You also have to join your imagess table on a foreign key.
There are errors in your query, "FROM text text_id" means you create an alias on text named text_id.

```
<?php
 $currentTextId = -1;
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM text, imagess WHERE (text.text_id=imagess.text_id) ORDER BY text.text_id");

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
     if($row['text_id']!=$currentTextId){
         $currentTextId=$row['text_id']
         echo '<br>№'.$row['text_id'].'<br>';
     }

     echo''.$row['title'].'<br>'.$row['text_field'];
     echo'<br><img src="'.$row['path'].'?url='.$row['path'].'/>';
 }

 ?>
```